# Reading arrays from file c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parameters, ifstream

I'm trying to make a program that so far only needs to read a file and saves its content in an array. the cout was a test to see if the words would be saved to the array but it didn't work. When executed all it does is print to screen empty spaces and finally the name of the file.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10000

void readFile(fstream& wordFile, string words[], int &wordarrayLength)
{
     string word;
     int i=0;

       while(i < MAX)
       {
           getline(wordFile,word);
           words[i] = word;
           i++;
           cout << words[i] << endl;
       }

     wordarrayLength = i;

     wordFile.close();
}

int main()
{

  string words[MAX];
  int arraylength;
  fstream file ("words.txt", ios::in);

  readFile(file,words,arraylength);

}
```

Comment: Pay careful attention: you save each line of text into `words[i]`, you increment `i`, and then print the contents of `words[i]`. Keep rereading the previous sentence until you figure out your bug.

Comment: Why don't you use a vector

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Edited the output to console line to `cout << word << endl;`and the result it's the same, I thought it was the way i was passing the file parameter but it seems fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way that `fstream` is being passed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand what you meant. the code stored the string in `words[i]` but the `cout` was the next string in the array which was yet to define... yet if i changed it `cout << word << endl;` the output should be the array extracted from the file, it's not,

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the file the compiler was looking for. This code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
//since you are updating the array pass it in by reference as well.
void readFile(fstream& wordFile, string &words[], int &wordarrayLength)
{
     int i=0;

       while(i < MAX)
       {
           //each item in the array has to be it's own string
           //the previous code simply reused the same string each time

           string word;
           getline(wordFile, word);
           words[i] = word;
           cout << words[i] << endl;
           i++;
       }

     wordarrayLength = i;

     wordFile.close();
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have your file or compiler so I can't debug it.